# Cascading Dropdown Issues in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have developed code that creates multiple cascading dropdowns, it works fine in IE8+ and FF.  My issue is, in IE7 I have to add an empty option to the select for it to work.  Here are two fiddles that demo both the functional and non functional code.  Why must I add the empty option?  Is there another underlying problem with my code?

Not working in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/k2vZr/2/

Working in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/k2vZr/1/
*Note: Notice I add an empty option to the drop down:

```
    var $dropdown3 = $('<select id="test3" class="myclass" name="samename"><option></option></select>').appendTo($('body'));
```

Also note that to test in IE7 from Windows 7, use the Developer Tools (Press: F12) in IE8 to switch the browser mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event handlers to something like:

```
$("#test").live("change", function(){
```

and

```
$("#test2").live("change", function(){
```

Comment: @kmb385 weird. When I run that fiddle in IE7 via the developer tools (win7) it is working correctly.